Calculating returns on sequence of trades with zero starting capital
Background
I am trying to calculate the returns on a sequence of trades performed by an entity, where I do not know the starting capital. Therefore I assume a starting capital of zero. From these returns I want to calculate the Sharpe ratio of a portfolio on which these trades are performed.
The initial idea of simply comparing successive portfolio values to calculate returns falls apart in this situation, for the following two numbered reasons.
A potential solution for calculating returns is to divide profits realised in a period by the gross market value of that period. The gross market value is the sum of the absolute values of all positions. I am interested in learning whether the returns calculated in this way are useful for calculating the Sharpe ratio.
Example
Suppose the price at $t_1$ of TSLA is 1000USD. I buy 1 TSLA for 1000USD. I am now long 1 TSLA and short 1000USD. My total portfolio value remains at 0USD.
At time $t_2$, the price of TSLA is 2000USD. Therefore my portfolio value is now 2000USD minus the 1000USD that I am short, which is 1000USD total.

Dividing the portfolio value at $t_2$ of 1000USD by the portfolio value at $t_1$ of 0USD, I realise an infinite return.

Suppose that at $t_3$ I now buy a further 999 TSLA at 2000USD. My portfolio value remains at 1000USD. At $t_4$, TSLA is now 3000USD. I am long 1000TSLA at 3000USD, so minus the 1999000USD that I am short, my portfolio value is 1001000USD.

Dividing the portfolio value at $t_4$ by the portfolio value at $t_3$ and subtracting 1, I have realised an outsize return of 1000, specifically because I went short a large number of USD compared with the amount of USD I was short previously.

I have looked at a number of resources online and in books, and of the resources that cover short positions and leverage, they generally assume a positive starting capital. This is not useful for my situation.
Possible Solution
One online resource I came across suggests dividing the profit in one period by what it calls the gross market value in that period. The gross market value is the sum of the absolute values of long and short positions. This takes account of the total capital at risk.
At $t_2$, our gross market value is 2000USD for the 1 TSLA, plus 1000USD for the short USD position. Therefore it is a total of 3000USD. Our profit realised between $t_1$ and $t_2$ is 1000USD, due to the 1000USD price increase. Therefore we have a return of 0.33.
The profit realised between $t_3$ and $t_4$ is 1000000USD. Dividing by the gross market value of 4999000 (value of TSLA held plus amount of USD that we are short) at $t_4$, we get a return of 0.2.
This seems like a more reasonable method of calculating returns. But questions still remain.

Is it correct to divide the profit in the current period by the gross market value in the current period, and not for instance by the average of the gross market value in the previous period and current period? Dividing by the latest gross market value makes more sense to me, as we are comparing profit in a period to the capital at risk during that period. ChatGPT suggested taking a time-weighted average of gross market values, but that sounded too complex to me.

Is it meaningful to calculate the Sharpe ratio from returns calculated in this way? Are there any sources in literature which recommend this method for the situation of zero starting capital?



There is no such thing as "zero starting capital"; every economic activity requires that you put up some capital (perhaps in unusual form such as sweat equity), no one will partner with you or lend you money if you put up nothing. No broker will allow you to short TSLA in an empty account (who will bear the loss if TSLA goes up?).

This is about assessing the worthiness of a sequence of trades where the initial starting capital is either irrelevant or unknown. To add some more context, I am interested in assessing the trades made by various wallets on decentralised cryptocurrency exchanges. The initial starting capital is unknown.

Personally, I read this as you are pursuing an entirely incorrect representation. Sharpe ratio is expected return divided by standard deviation capital at risk, and it is usually used "ex ante" as a way of comparing different potential trades and bet sizing. This means that one's starting capital is irrelevant, you have to assess the capital at risk of the supposed trade. "ex post" performance measurement is a different thing. You could measure this on a similar scale by evaluating the capital at risk over a period an comparing it to the return achieved.

@Attack68 Does my definition of gross market value at the end of the "Background" section fit what you mean by capital at risk?

No. capital at risk is a measure of how volatile the instrument is and the amount of exposure to that instrument. If you trade derivatives you have no market value, but you will have capital at risk. In terms of securities, TESLA is a volatile stock: it has much more capital at risk for a held position of $100,000 (100 shares at $1000) than does $100,000 of IB01 (1000 shares at $100), which has a much lower volatility.

Hi jkut: Not to sound rude but I stopped reading when you wrote the following because it's incorrect. You wrote "Dividing the portfolio value at $t_{2}$ of 1000USD by the portfolio value at $t_{1}$ of 0USD, I realise an infinite return.". You don't realize an infinite return because you need to divide by what was invested and that investment was 1000 USD. So, the return is not infinite. You need to understand that step BEFORE you go further so let us know if that makes sense.

@markleeds Thanks for the reply, but there is something that keeps me from following your interpretation. I made a 1000USD investment, but to do that I went short 1000USD, so the initial portfolio value remained zero. I feel that disregarding the short amount would somehow be cheating. Hence the gross market value idea. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Hi jkut: There's nothing wrong with your scenario. The initial capital invested is 1000 USD. So don't think of yourself as short 1000USD. Think of it as what you invested to create your holdings in the stock. Now, when you calculate your return to holding that stock, the capital invested is 1000USD. Don't think of it as being short 1000USD. You're not getting anything for being short 1000USD except that stock ( the 1000USD isn't being lent to someone say ) so not reason to think of yourself as short. I hope that helps.

@markleeds Let’s make the short long instead. Say I start with 2000USD and buy 1 TSLA at 1000USD.  I have 1000USD remaining. The price of TSLA goes to 2000USD. My profit is 1000USD. Would I not divide that by 2000USD (1000 for the TSLA and the 1000 remaining) to get the return? Dividing the profit by the 1000 invested alone would seem wrong to me.

Hi Jkut: Why does it seem wrong ?  It doesn't make sense to divide by the 2000 because you only used 1000 to buy the share. The capital you divide by is the capital used to make the investment. The extra 1000 is just sitting there and wasted so that should go in the bank and get the interest rate. Don't leave it sitting there. Does that make sense ? I want to explain this because I'm sure you can get it but I'm not sure how.

think about it this way. you have a million dollars. you spend 1000 on a share. Then the return you get on that share has nothing to with the 999K you didn't spend on the share.

@markleeds I would say that money unused represents an opportunity cost of the strategy, and that it should be included in calculating the portfolio value. Would you agree with this?

Hi jkut: yes. absolutely it's an opportunity cost. So, put that unused money in the bank or lend it to someone or buy more stocks. Until you do something with that money, it should not be included in the return calculation. If you tell me what you do with that money, then I can show you how to continue with the caclulation. Right now, 999K is just being wasted. There is opportunity cost but you need to know the alternatives and invest it in one of those so that it's not wasted. Then, you can include it in the return calculation.

Note that, if you put the 999K in the bank and got interest, then we could include that in the overall return calculation but it would be a seperate term in the calculation and unrelated to the 1000 you spent on the stock. If you want to know how that calc would work, let me know.

@markleeds I would like to keep the money available to use by the strategy at any time. With this in mind, how should I compute returns?

@markleeds What I am getting at is this: If I start with 1000USD, I invest 1USD and it is now worth 2USD, should I really register a 100% return in light of the remaining 999USD?

yes, you can keep the money available to use but then don't include it in the return calc. I agree that it is kind of being wasted by sitting there. It should atleast be getting the available overnight return. To your second comment, absolutely : The return is 100 percent. I hope this makes sense.

I was thinking about this a little more and it is somewhat terminology driven. With your way of doing it, you are trying to calculate the return on the 1000USD. But it's not realistic because no one would calculate the return on a portfolio where 999USD of the 1000USD was just sitting there doing nothing. The 100 percent is the return on your INVESTMENT of 1USD. If you want the return on your portfolio ( the 1000USD), you should do something with the  other 999USD. Otherwise, the portfolio return calculation is kind of biased. Some would probably say its wrong.

@markleeds Just to develope this idea a bit: I start with 1000USD. at T_1 I buy 1 TSLA at 1USD. I have 999USD remaining. At T_2, the price of TSLA goes up to 2USD,  and I buy 1 more TSLA. I now have 2 TSLA and 997USD remaining. What is my return at T_2? Should I be calculating the return only on the 1 TSLA I had at T_1? What if I had sold my 1 TSLA at T_2 instead of buying 1 TSLA? I would then hold 0 TSLA at T_2. What would my return at T_2 thus be?

Hi Jkut: let me print this out, read it carefully tonight and hopefully send some kind of useful response.

I put an answer below ( needed space ) but it's really an answer to your latest comment and not to the original question. Obviously, it's related.

Hi Jkut: First you should always specify the return in the sense of when you calculate the return, what are you calculating the return of ? In our case, we will calculate the return on the two share purchases you described.
You purchased 1 share at T1 at 1USD.
During T1 to T2, the price went from 1USD to 2USD.
At T2, you then purchase an additional share at 2USD.
Let us make 2 additional assumptions.
Suppose that, between T2 and T3, the price went up another 1USD.
Also suppose that, at T3, you sold all of your shares at 3USD per share. So, T3 is when you completely stopped investing.
Given the information above, we can calculate
A)  the return from T1 to T2
B)  the return from T2 to T3.
C)  possibly the return from T1 to T3. ( we shall see )
A) At T1, you bought 1 share at 1USD. Beween T1 to T2, the share went
up to 2USD. So, the return = (dollars made or lost over the period due to
total investment at the beginning of the period )/(total investment in
dollars at  the beginning of the period).
So, the return from T1 to T2 due to the 1 share purchase at T1 =
(2USD -1USD)/1USD = 100 percent.
B) At T2, you bought another share at 2USD. Then, from T2 to T3, the price
went to 3USD.
The return from T2 to T3 due to the 1 share purchase at T2 = (3USD - 2USD)/2USD = 50 percent.
The return from T2 to T3 due to the original share ( bought at T1) still being held from T2 to T3 = (3USD - 2USD)/2USD = 50 percent.
So, each of the shares returned 50 percent from T2 to T3. Equivalently, we can also say that the return on the portfolio of 2 shares from T2 to T3 = 2USD/4USD = 50 percent. This is because you had 2 shares so the investment was worth 4USD at T2. Then, at T3, it was valued at 6USD. So, (6USD - 4USD)/4USD = 50 percent.
C) There is no conventional way that I know of to calculate the return from T1 to T3 because the investment amount is changing over the period. I would probably just calculate the returns from from (T1 to T2) and (T2 to T3).
Notice that you can calculate dollar profit from T1 to T2 as 1USD and
dollar profit from T2 to T3 as 2USD. So, total dollar profit from
T1 to T3 is 3USD. But it's not really possible to calculate the return
from T1 to T3 because the investment amount changes. There is a way to approximate it but I'd rather not get into that unless you're interested. I don't regard  it as all that useful of an approximation.
#===============================================================
You mentioned  consdering the alternative senario where you sold the 1 share at T2 and ended your investing stint right there. The return on the 1 share
would still be 50 percent from T1 to T2. This is because the calculation is EXACTLY THE SAME as it was when you didn't sell the share because the formula only needs
( how much did I make or lose over the period ) divided by the dollar
investment. So, selling the share at T2, makes no difference in the calculation from T1 to T2.  Of course, in that case, the investment is finished and nothing happens in the period from T2 to T3.
I hope this helped to clear up the return calculation. If you think of it as I defined it, then I think you can't go wrong. If anything was not clear, let me know.

The above discussion was bizarre gobbledygook, return is calculated by arithmetic method (t2 -t1)/ t2 or log returns ln(t1/t2) where t = time and numbers represent time sequences. That is the capital gain,I have no idea what or where you got those ideas about measuring shares from, the Sharpe ratio is simply rt/ s where s = sample standard deviation. And rt is return at time = t,sometimes the numerator is expressed as rt- rf/ s or return at t minus risk free rate over stdev.

In evaluating shares your capital is irrelevant to the Sharpe ratio it is only used for measuring return on investment and as for capital growth rate there is various approaches and you need not use initial capital to compare shares performances only your portfolio capital growth.

If you are shorting stocks or using hedged derivatives we are talking a whole nother ball game and you are in the wrong park with this stuff.

Sorry the first formulas for calculating return had the incorrect nomenclature replace t with St and st-1 for share at time t and time t minus 1 for previous period,,not r as r is the result or return.

jkut: don't pay attention to the 1st, 2nd and 4th comments above because they are not helpful and will only add to any existing confusion.

jkut: Note that the actual formula for arithmetic return from t1 to t2 is $\frac{(P_{t2} - P_{t1})}{P_{t1}}$ where $P_{t}$ denotes the price at time $t$.  I did not phrase it that way in the answer because I wanted to provide the intuition rather than a formula.

if comments are unhelpful, please delete them, or change, thanks.

I'm not sure what the appropriate edicate is but I'm not gonna change what people write. In fact, when I made the not helpful comment to jkut, I should have said "IMHO", so my apologies for leaving that out. Others may find them useful so I definitely won't touch them.

I was addressing jkut's original nonsense not your highly confused attempts at correcting, the guy should buy a book on intro to quant finance such as Paul Willmots or Luenbergers Investment Science standard texts, he is way off beam. I have no idea where he got his ideas. And he thinks he has made a great discovery?

I agree that what what jkut is asking could be discerned from a book by some. But others may prefer an explanation from a person. I really don't analyze people's motives If I have the time and I think that my explanation may help someone, I'll provide one. If you don't like a question or explanation, you are definitely entitled to that opinion. But everyone is different. I used to hang out at DSP stackexchange for a while. I'm confident that the questions I asked there were of a similar level to the present one.

Questions vary depending on the person and the person's background and abilities in the field. It's all just about learning. Oh, on this site, I often spend hours going through what someone else came up with ( and latexed ) in minutes.

Indeed on stack exchange excel and python and R page I am guilty of stupid simple questions several years ago.

I think chatgpt has taken a lot of the silly questions off site, people can sort it out quicklynow.

yeah, sometimes something someone says will just make it "click" for the person who asked the question. Sometimes not.  In general, we are so lucky to have these stackechange sites. It's free teaching ( from experts ) and learning ( from experts ).
